# How to show page numbers at the bottom of each page?

Tags: header-footer, page-numbering, pagestyle

I try to add numbering at the bottom of each page, using the code shown below. But I found that the page number appears in the header, with the `Outline of Proposed Research`, rather than at the bottom of each page. How to edit it?

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[margin=0.75in]{geometry}
\usepackage{mathptmx} 

\pagestyle{headings}
\markboth{}{ Outline of Proposed Research}

\setcounter{secnumdepth}{0}
\pagenumbering{arabic}
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}
\linespread{1.0}

\begin{document} 
...
\end{document}
```

Comment: Take a look at e.g. `fandyhdr`.

Comment: `\pagestyle{plain}` also puts the page number at the bottom of the page, but no headers.  Actually, you don't need any packages to create your own page style (such as `\ps@myheader`)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As @cfr has suggested in a comment, you should take a look at the [fancyhdr](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/fancyhdr) package and its user macros.

The following code

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[margin=0.75in]{geometry}
\usepackage{mathptmx} 

\usepackage{fancyhdr}
% First, define desired elements of the 'fancy' page style:
\fancyhead[R]{Outline of Proposed Research} % top-right
\renewcommand{\headrule}{} % no header rule
\fancyfoot[C]{\thepage} % bottom-center
\pagestyle{fancy} % Second, switch to this 'fancy' page style

\usepackage{lipsum} % filler text

\begin{document} 
\lipsum[1-14] % 2 pages of filler text
\end{document}
```

produces the output shown below. Note that I've highlighted the running header ("Outline of Proposed Research") at the upper right and the page numbers at bottom-center. You're obviously free to adjust the placement of these document elements to suit your needs.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

There are [several packages to configure the page header and footer](https://ctan.org/topic/page-hf). Mico has already shown an example using [`fancyhdr`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/fancyhdr). Here one with [`scrlayer-scrpage`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/scrlayer-scrpage):

```latex
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[margin=0.75in]{geometry}
\usepackage{mathptmx} 

\usepackage[manualmark,pagestyleset=KOMA-Script]{scrlayer-scrpage}
\markright{Outline of Proposed Research}% set the \rightmark to "Outline of Proposed Research"

\setcounter{secnumdepth}{0}
%\pagenumbering{arabic}% default and therefore not needed
%\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}% not recommended → https://sourceforge.net/p/koma-script/wiki-en/HowTo_NoParIndent/ …
\usepackage{parskip}% … is the better solution to not indent the first line of a paragraph
%\linespread{1.0}% default and therefore not needed

\usepackage{mwe}

\begin{document}
\blinddocument
\end{document}
```

[image: scrlayer-scrpage solution with centered manual header and centered page number in the footer]

Note: `\markright` does not set the right mark of the page header, but the right part of the standard LaTeX mark originally (e.g. with page style `myheadings` or `headings` of the standard classes) supposed to be used for right (odd) pages. On single-sided documents, this mark is by default used for odd and even pages. See a LaTeX introduction or the KOMA-Script manual for more information about `\markright` and `\markboth`. See the KOMA-Script manual also for information about `\markdouble`, which could be used here instead of `\markright` and which could be useful for double-sided documents (e.g., if using class option `twoside`).

In your case only the two lines

```latex
\usepackage[manualmark,pagestyleset=KOMA-Script]{scrlayer-scrpage}
\markright{Outline of Proposed Research}
```

are needed, because it seems, that the predefined page style set `KOMA-Script` already shows the wanted result with a head mark in the middle of the page header and pagination in the middle of the footer. In other cases, [more configuration could be needed](https://sourceforge.net/p/koma-script/wiki-en/HowTo_PageHeadFoot/).

Using [`titleps`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/titleps) would also be possible:

```latex
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[margin=0.75in]{geometry}
\usepackage{mathptmx} 

\usepackage{titleps}
\newpagestyle{outline}{
  \sethead{}{Outline of Proposed Research}{}% header {left}{center}{right}
  \setfoot{}{\thepage}{}% footer {left}{center}{right}
}
\pagestyle{outline}

\setcounter{secnumdepth}{0}
%\pagenumbering{arabic}% default and therefore not needed
%\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}% not recommended → https://sourceforge.net/p/koma-script/wiki-en/HowTo_NoParIndent/ …
\usepackage{parskip}% … is the better solution to not indent the first line of a paragraph
%\linespread{1.0}% default and therefore not needed

\usepackage{mwe}

\begin{document}
\blinddocument
\end{document}
```

The result is the same as shown above.

Answer (score 1):

Just another solution for the record: One could also use kernel macros to style the header and the footer. I created a new pagestyle `hermisheading` which is loaded as usual with `\pagestyle{hermisheading}` and produces the wanted output.

The shown code is very simple and overrides many other macros (`\sectionmark`,`\@mkboth`) to force the declared headings on every page. Thus, I **do not recommend** using it, its **just an example**. The packages proposed by @cabohah and @Mico offer much more sophisticated and understandable solutions.

But maybe the kernel code gives a better insight and supports understanding how these things work in the background (where they are much more elaborated: the code for pagestyle `headings` has nearly four times as many lines).

```latex
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[margin=0.75in]{geometry}

\makeatletter
\if@twoside
  \def\ps@hermisheading{%
    \def\@evenhead{\hfil\slshape\leftmark\hfil}%
    \def\@oddhead{\hfil\slshape\rightmark\hfil}%
    \def\@evenfoot{\hfil\thepage\hfil}%
    \def\@oddfoot{\hfil\thepage\hfil}%
  }
\else
  \def\ps@hermisheading{%
    \def\@oddhead{\hfil\slshape\rightmark\hfil}%
    \def\@oddfoot{\hfil\thepage\hfil}%
  }
\fi
\makeatother

\pagestyle{hermisheading}

\markboth{Outline of Proposed Research}{Outline of Proposed Research} % just in case you want to use it with a twosided document


\setcounter{secnumdepth}{0}

\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}
\linespread{1.0}

\usepackage{blindtext}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\blinddocument

\end{document}
```